# Google Play Download Technique

Tags: android

We have seen that when we are logged into our ***Google Play*** account from **Desktop** and than we select one app for download and it automatically starts download into our Phone.

So my question is that **How is it working behind the scenes?**

Means if one Service is countinuously checking for "is there any app to download?" and trigger the download that is too much battery consuming task and interval is not used into google play service like at the moment we click on install from desktop it will start download the application.So which kind of logic is using their side?

Is is only a service running continuous behind this magic, so it would be inefficient way for doing so...

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your device's running service you will find two service always running for google 
play store named **PendingNotificationsService** and **ContentSyncService**, those are doing this tricks.

Comment: but running this kind of service all the time would be very inefficient way to do so, and even after running service means its is checking on server all the time that is there any application to install??right?? and if so how could server handle this many request of devices on earth at the same time??

Comment: @lunar4dev, On the server-side, it's using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging), which is a centralized barebones low level triggering mechanism (with no guarantee of delivery, although it retries three times). This push-notification system is an event-based system. It works just like SMS, or the phone service. If you think about it, those two also work in real-time. By offering this service for free to all developers, Google guarantees that developers don't try to develop their own separate system. Creating your own push-notification system separate from GCM decreases the daily battery life by 10%.

Answer (score 0):

This market download functionality is working on top of push notifications. I.e. when you click in your browser to install an app, google play checks what the phones are connected to your account. Then it sends to your phone a special notification and your phone starts to install the packet.